# problems iterating and filling array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

May be a silly question but im struggling here. Im iterating through an api and i only want to insert in the array the elements that meet a condition. With the below code im only getting the first result repeated two times.

```
        (state.data || []).map((details) => (
            (details.events || []).map((values) => (
                (values.dataValues || []).map((results) => (
                    ((results.code ==='y1z7anzbp5r')) ? (

                        array.push([{data: values.eventDate, value: results.value}])

                    ):(null)
                ))

            ))
        ))
```

is anything wrong with the iterations?

Comment: I suggest you look at other `map()` examples online. You shouldn't call `push()` with `map()` because `map()` already creates an array for you. With that said, please post a [mcve] with all variables declared so we can understand the context of the code you ar asking about. Be sure to pay special attention to indenting when you post code here. It's very difficult to tell what each closing parentheses goes with.

Comment: you have a map in there that returns nothing... several times.
map iterates over each element and makes a new array - but if it doesn't return it implicitly goes undefined... I think instead of map, forEach would be better- that doesn't return a value just does an action over each element in the array.

Comment: on another note - PLEASE use {} for declaring scope when appropriate- () is hell to parse for humans.

Comment: @altruios - He is returning. He's using implicit return.

Comment: @technicallynick but what he's returning is array.push():null... so he's returning undefined or null, and I thought implicit needed to be on the same line? is that the reason for the () instead of {} does that allow for implicits on lower lines?

Comment: @altruios - Precisesly. () basically says "resolve what's inside for the value".

Comment: merg... my approach has always been, if it needs 2 or more lines of statements:you are in a block/scope... so define the scope with {}. implicit value returns I had always assumed to be one line! (learn something new every day) but I don't think I'll change up my style (double '))' instead of ')}' is harder to tell which bracket is for what IMO) but that's good to know... I don't see () as often as {} for those reasons I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use a filter at the end. It reduces the complication of your code and makes it so that your final array will only an array of items with your desired code.

```js
(state.data ?? []).map((details) => (details.events ?? []).map((values) => (values.dataValues ?? []).filter((results) => results.code === 'y1z7anzbp5r')))
```